# Is => just a short hand for property get set syntax?

Tags: c#

Are both the below same? If yes, then what's the point of this optimization? For example - suppose I want to keep code readable and say have multiple lines of code in the get/set then I MUST use Sample 2 approach?

Sample 1:

```
public class SaleItem
{
   string _name;

   public string Name
   {
      get => _name;
      set => _name = value;
   }
}
```

Sample 2:

```
public class SaleItem
{
   string _name;

   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set { _name=value; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes. There are [expression-bodies members](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/)

Comment: Yes. Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Comment: Ok so suppose I want to make the get or set logic multiple lines, then I MUST use the Sample 2 approach?

Comment: Yes I think so .

Comment: There are a large number of property implementations that may be a) more complex than just accessing a backing field (so cannot be auto-implemented) and b) still just one line, and benefit from the reduced syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's same things.
https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMoEMA2ApgJIAuhAtsgN7Lr1RwAM6A+gHa4WEDcydDDIxYA5LoQHpaSerPQBzQqXQBeAHxtO3PjLnoAzktUaO41egBuBAK69JAX2T2gA

```
public class SaleItem
{
   string _name;

   public string Name
   {
      get => _name;
      set => _name = value;
   }
}
```

it's decomplie to

```
public class SaleItem
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this optimization? For example - suppose I want to keep code readable and say have multiple lines of code in the get/set then I MUST use Sample 2 approach?

Comment: well , if you can write less code , and it's worked. I think it's be more readable for me in this case.

Comment: it's called [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) and not optimization because it doesn't optimize anything, just a different way to express something

Answer (score 2):

> Are both the below same?

Yes

> If yes, then what's the point of this optimization?

I personally don't feel there is one, and I use the {} approach

> For example - suppose I want to keep code readable and say have multiple lines of code in the get/set then I MUST use Sample 2 approach?

Yes. If you think about it, the way you'd normally write a multi line value-returning expression (enclose it in braces, put a return at the end) makes it 2 chars longer for the `=>`

```
public string Name{
  get => {
    if(x==y) return a;
    return b;
  }
}

public string Name{
  get {
    if(x==y) return a; 
    return b;
  }
}
```

so there doesn't seem much point supporting it

What does an expression bodied property give you? Saves you a few bytes of not having to type `return` in the get. You don't save anything on the curly braces because you have to type `=>`

If you're going to have "simple get/set that just returns/sets a backing field" you can tidy the code down to just

```
public string Name{get;set;}
```

and skip the backing field part (use the property within the class to get/set the value)

If you're going to have a read only property and backing field you can:

```
public string Name => _name;
```

The other two options (in your question) are identical; pick whichever one you think looks tidier

If you're making a class that mostly holds data you can simplify your life by using a record:

```
public record SaleItem(string Name);
```

That's all you need to type, and it functions like the class you have there in terms of being a reference type and having an externally visible property Name. You add more props between the parentheses, and the compiler generates a constructor for you that looks the same:

```
var s = new SaleItem("socks");
```

As well as overriding equals and some other good stuff. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records#characteristics-of-records)